Separate action in action.yml in actions folder is not called in workflow file
Having below workflow file in GitHub repo inside .github/workflows folder which works fine:
# .github/workflows/markdown-lint.yml

name: markdown-lint
run-name: learning github action from workflow
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - develop
jobs:
  markdown-lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Node.js environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: "20"

      - name: Lint Markdown files
        run: |
          npx markdownlint-cli '**/*.md' \
          --config '.github/workflows/.markdownlint.json' \
          --ignore '.github/CONTRIBUTING.md' \
          --ignore '.github/CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md'\
          --ignore 'CHANGELOG.md'

Now I want to separate the run command part so that we can re-use, so create a folder ./github/actions/md-lint/ and put below code:
# .github/actions/md-lint/action.yml

 run: |
          npx markdownlint-cli '**/*.md' \
          --config '.github/workflows/.markdownlint.json' \
          --ignore '.github/CONTRIBUTING.md' \
          --ignore '.github/CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md'\
          --ignore 'CHANGELOG.md'

and add it in markdown-lint.yml file as below:
 - name: Lint Markdown files
   uses: ././github/actions/md-lint/

but it doesn't work, it throws an error:
markdown-lint
Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/home/runner/work/template/template/.github/actions/md-lint/action.yml'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?

Also tried with composite as per documentation:
# .github/actions/md-lint/action.yml

runs: 
using: 'composite'
run: |
  npx markdownlint-cli '**/*.md' \
  --config './github/actions/.markdownlint.json' \
  --ignore '.github/CONTRIBUTING.md' \
  --ignore '.github/CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md'\
  --ignore 'CHANGELOG.md'


but it gives below error
Error: /home/runner/work/template/template/./.github/actions/md-lint/action.yml (Line: 1, Col: 6): Unexpected value ''
Error: System.ArgumentException: Unexpected type 'NullToken' encountered while reading 'runs'. The type 'MappingToken' was expected.
   at GitHub.DistributedTask.ObjectTemplating.Tokens.TemplateTokenExtensions.AssertMapping(TemplateToken value, String objectDescription)
   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.ActionManifestManager.ConvertRuns(IExecutionContext executionContext, TemplateContext templateContext, TemplateToken inputsToken, String fileRelativePath, MappingToken outputs)
   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.ActionManifestManager.Load(IExecutionContext executionContext, String manifestFile)
Error: Failed to load /home/runner/work/template/template/./.github/actions/md-lint/action.yml

How can we achive this by keeping all run command separately in actions/ folder and add references in workflows/ files?

Indentation matters in YAML (and steps is an array of objects, not a string); what you're showing is not a valid composite action metadata file.

okay so can we replace steps with run

Considering that you are checking out your repo and that the action is in the same repo, it is possible to refer to your action via relative path. However, a few changes are required to define and invoke your action.
The workflow - typo in ././github:
# .github/workflows/markdown-lint.yml

name: markdown-lint
run-name: learning github action from workflow
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - develop
jobs:
  markdown-lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Setup Node.js environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: "20"
      - name: Lint Markdown files
        uses: ./.github/actions/md-lint

The action - description is required, shell is required and indentation has to follow action schema:
# .github/actions/md-lint/action.yml

name: md-lint

description: Run npx markdownlint-cli

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - shell: bash
      run: |
        npx markdownlint-cli '**/*.md' \
        --config '.github/workflows/.markdownlint.json' \
        --ignore '.github/CONTRIBUTING.md' \
        --ignore '.github/CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md'\
        --ignore 'CHANGELOG.md'

You may want to consider placing action directory under the root of the project. This will simplify relative path:
      - name: Lint Markdown files
        uses: ./md-lint


Thanks it worked. additionaly I have movied .markdownlint.json file within actions/md-lint folder and changed in action.yml as --config ./.markdownlint.json
